# I am not able to figure out how to pass Bundle in mapview.onCreate() in custom viewholder class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, fragment-lifecycle

i have a generic viewholder class for  recyclerview which uses MapView inside that row, and the viewholder class is extending my base viewholder abstract class which has populateData(TO to), i am initializing map in the constructor of my viewholder class and passing null to mapview.onCreate(null).

my classes are look like this

```
public class MyViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder implements OnReadyMapCallBack{

   private MapView mapView;
   public MyViewHolder(View view){

       mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map);
       mapView.onCreate(null); //here i should pass Bundle instead


      }
// this method is declared in parent class abstract class

@override    
public void populateData(TO to){ 
     mapView.getAsync(this);
}
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You trued this:

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key",value);

    mapView.onCreate(args);
```

?

Comment: i have not tried this approach..i will try it definitely, thanks for reply. my only worry is the way i am integrating map view in non activity class could cause any bugs? because mapFragment is having its own life cycle and i am not using any of the method of life cycle.

Comment: Just follow this and put the bundle as I mentioned. If you implement all the lifecycle methods you will be ok! https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: but its a recyclerview holder which will be used by the time of inflating recyclerview row, so i have to configure implementation of map in viewholder itself not in any fragment.